# In React-Native + hooks: updating parent's value multiple times in a row from a child component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

The objective is to create an input component where the user can click a button, which if held, would fire an action multiple times (e.g. think here of a `+` button, which would increment continuously the parent's value). The firing stops when the button is released.

The below code is the minimum code to highlight both the needed infrastructure (parent/child) and the issue I am facing.

The issue: when pressing, the `count` value is incremented only once, although the incrementor is fired multiple times. The parent owns both the `count` value and the `onChange` callback (along the `<TextInput>` pattern)

I believe it comes from that the `value` in `incr()` is set to the value at `MyInput` render time; As long as the button is not released, `MyInput` is not re-rendered, hence the incrementor is still bound to that original `value`.

Parent Component:

```js
const Screen = ({}) => {
  const [ count, setCount ] = useState(0);
  
  const onChange = (value) => {
    setCount(value);
  }
  
  return (
    <View style={{ flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center' }}>
      <Text>Parent: [{count}]</Text>
      <MyInput value={count} onChange={onChange}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Child Component: `MyInput` follows `<TextInput>` and similar patterns where the `value` is owned by the parent and updated via an `onChange` callback

```js
export const MyInput = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  const [ timer, setTimer ] = useState(null);

  const incr = () => {
    const nv = value + 1;
    console.warn(new Date(), `nv: ${nv}`);
    onChange(value + 1);
  }

  const onPressIn = () => {
    setTimer(setInterval(incr, 10));
    // or calling incr() twice here, would have the same effect
  };

  const onPressOut = () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Child: {value}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPressIn={onPressIn}
        onPressOut={onPressOut}>
        <Text>+</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
};
```

I could partially solve the situation if I use a local state copy of the value (say `[ localValue, setLocalValue ] = useState(value)` in `MyInput`, and use `setLocalValue(xxx => xxx+1)` ... however it would only update the local value and not the parent's one.

Maybe force refreshing would be a (bad) option too?

I tried around with useCallback/... however, as it seems, I would need to release the button before the parent gets re-rendered (or something like that).

The constraints are: functional-components & hooks and the `value/onChange` parent owned props

Any idea how I could solve the above situation?
thanks in advance for any hints

Answer (score 0):

```js
import {useEffect}from 'react'

export const MyInput = ({ value, onChange }) => {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

const incr = () => {
    const nv = value + 1;
    // console.warn(new Date(), `nv: ${nv}`);
    onChange(value + 1);
}
useEffect(() => {
    incr()
    setTimer(setInterval(incr, 10));
}, [value])
const onPressIn = () => {
    // setTimer(setInterval(incr, 10));
    // or calling incr() twice here, would have the same effect
    onChange(value + 1);
};

const onPressOut = () => {
    clearInterval(timer);
};
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Child: {value}</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPressIn={onPressIn}
        onPressOut={onPressOut}>
        <Text>+</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
};
```

Comment: try to do your stuff in useEffect it will run when your parent state change hope the above solution will work

Comment: thanks @mubashir for your answer: the good (but also bad) news is that now I don't even have to press on the button for the incrementor to be called; that is because the effect is only considered when value is set the first time by the parent, hence the Interval is started ... but also everytime the Interval has updated the value; so it ends with a infinite loop of updating `value` at different state ...; In addition it seems that the `useEffect(,[value])` is only called once the button is released ... e.g. parent does not seem to be re-rendered